# Unresolved dependency with xgboost library in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt, xgboost

I've added my xgboost jar files in the library and modules in my project structure. (I built the jar files from source successfully as mentioned in the documentation). I can't seem to be able to resolve the dependency for it. I've tried to run it with the dependency included in the build sbt file and with it taken out (since the jars are already included in the library and dependencies via the project structure). Both seem to be failing. Is this some sort of a compatibility issue? I am running scala 2.11.8 and spark 2.1.0. My dependencies are included in a sequence as follows:

```
"ml.dmlc" %% "xgboost4j" % "0.7", "ml.dmlc" %% "xgboost4j-spark" % "0.7"
```

I seem to be missing something but I am not sure what. Any ideas?

I tried to publish the jar as suggested but I get the following error:

```
    sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: ml.dmlc#xgboost4j_2.11;0.7: not found
unresolved dependency: ml.dmlc#xgboost4j-spark_2.11;0.7: not found
        at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:313)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:191)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:168)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:156)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:156)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:133)
        at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:57)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:65)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:65)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:128)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:125)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:156)
        at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:168)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1439)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1435)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$90.apply(Defaults.scala:1470)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$90.apply(Defaults.scala:1468)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:37)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1473)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1467)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:60)
        at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1490)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1417)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1369)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: ml.dmlc#xgboost4j_2.11;0.7: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: ml.dmlc#xgboost4j-spark_2.11;0.7: not found
[error] Total time: 24 s, completed Aug 15, 2017 12:40:52 PM
```

Comment: You can either build a jar from source and treat it as an unmanaged dependency or pull a jar from maven and treat it as a managed dependency.

Comment: Alternatively, you can publish the jars for xgboost to an artifactory... to prototype, publish them to your local ivy directory. In sbt, `sbt publish-local` and in maven, `mvn install` (from within xgboost dir). This is what you'll need to do for xgboost.

Comment: @erip it has to be treated as a unmanaged dependency I guess as the xgboost4j needs to be built from source. I tried to build from source but that still doesn't really resolve the dependency. I updated the question!

Comment: I thought it might be but I have errors with compilation and dependency warnings so I wasn't sure if it is the same reason. I am also wondering if it might be because of the versions. @erip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency should only have one % there.

```
"ml.dmlc" % "xgboost4j" % "0.7", "ml.dmlc" % "xgboost4j-spark" % "0.7"
```